# Having problems with regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, palindrome

I am currently making a senior memory book my English class, and because I'm a nerd I am going to put a bit of code in it. Well, I'm having a bit of trouble with regex in my code.
My entire code:

```js
//For future reference, "alert(*parametes*)" will make an alert box with the parameters inside it.

//Asks you to enter a phrase and stores your answer.
var phrase = prompt("Enter a phrase to be checked for palindrome.").toLowerCase()
//Creates the entered phrase backwards.
var phraseBackwards = ""
for (var x in phrase) {
  phraseBackwards += phrase[(phrase.length - 1) - x]
}
//Checks to see if the new phrase is a palindrome.
if (phraseBackwards == phrase) {
  alert("The phrase you entered was a palindrome.")
}
//This happens if the preavious condition was false.
else {
  //Checks if the new phrase is a palindrome without spaces.
  if (phraseBackwards.replace("/\s+/g", '') == phrase) {
    alert("The phrase you entered would have been a palindrome, had it not had spaces")
  } else {
    //Checks to see if the phrase you entered, even without spaces, is not a palindrome.
    if (phraseBackwards.replace(/\s+/g, '') != phrase) {
      alert("The phrase you ented was not a palindrome.")
    }
  }
}
```

The particular portion that is not functioning correctly:

```js
//Checks if the new phrase is a palindrome without spaces.
if (phraseBackwards.replace(/\s+/g, '') == phrase) {
  alert("The phrase you entered would have been a palindrome, had it not had spaces")
}
```

I realize that some of my code may not be optimal but I'm trying to hurry and finish because I procrastinated until last minute.

Comment: Define "not functioning correctly"

Comment: Since "Madam I'm Adam" is considered a palindrome even though it has spaces (and an apostrophe) perhaps you need to handle that part differently.

Comment: Why do you have `"/\s+/g"` in one line and `/\s+/g` in the other?

Comment: phraseBackwards without spaces can't be == to the original phrase, because the original has spaces. Remove spaces from the original phrase as well.

Comment: [This will help from next time.](http://waitbutwhy.com/2013/10/why-procrastinators-procrastinate.html) ☺☻

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few points to note in my edit.

First of all, you need to remove all non word characters from the initial phrase using this: `replace(/\W/g, "")`

Then reverse the string: `phrase.split("").reverse().join("")`

Then check if `phraseBackwards == phrase`.

Note: The code you used to used to reverse the string was valid. But given your use for this, I thought you might want to make it shorter.

```js
//For future reference, "alert(*parameters*)" will make an alert box with the parameters inside it.

//Asks you to enter a phrase and stores your answer.
var phrase = prompt("Enter a phrase to be checked for palindrome.").toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, "");

//Creates the entered phrase backwards.
var phraseBackwards = phrase.split("").reverse().join("");
//Checks to see if the new phrase is a palindrome.
if (phraseBackwards == phrase) {
 alert("The phrase you entered was a palindrome.");
}
//This happens if the previous condition was false.
else {
 alert("The phrase you ented was not a palindrome.");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

phraseBackwards without spaces can't be == to the original phrase, because the original has spaces. Remove spaces from the original phrase as well. – Jeremy Thille